# JSF2.0 Resource library subfolder file retrieval

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish-3

How do I reference a file inside the subfolder of the image library with JSF2.0?

[image: JSF2.0 Image subfolder]

I have tried many ways using the library and name tag but the most logical seems to be the one below, but it doesn't work!

```
<h:graphicImage library="images" name="Mecearia\4382982_med.jpg"/>
```

The server always returns

```
WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, Mecearia\4382982_med.jpg, from library, images.
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL path separator is `/`, not `\`.

```
<h:graphicImage library="images" name="Mecearia/4382982_med.jpg"/>
```

---

By the way, you're not using `library` the right way. It should represent a "theme", not a duplication of whatever the `<h:graphicImage>` (and `<h:outputScript>` and `<h:outputStylesheet>`) tag by itself already tells. If you don't have any (thus just the "default" theme), remove it and use

```
<h:graphicImage name="images/Mecearia/4382982_med.jpg"/>
```

#### See also:

- [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used/)